# QPushButton setEnabled(true) slot does not work

Tags: qt4

I have a push button which I set disabled by default . I want that whenever some text is entered in a textbox, the button will be enabled. I am trying this:

```
connect(ui->textEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged()),ui->pushButton,SLOT(setEnabled(true)));
```

But gives following error:

```
Object::connect: No such slot QPushButton::setEnabled(true)
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'textEdit')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'pushButton')
```

Qt official documentation says it inherits setEnabled() slot from QWidget 
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#public-slots

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong :

- `void QPushButton::setEnabled(bool);` is not a Qt slot.
- The signal and the slot which are connected through the `static void QObject::connect(const QObject *, const char *, const QObject *, const char *);` method have to get the same signature. Here you got a "`blablablaSignal(void);`" signal with a "`blablablaSlot(bool);`" slot.
- You must not pass arguments while connecting slots.
- The `void QLineEdit::textChanged(void);` signal does not exist, unlike `void QLineEdit::textChanged(const QString &);`.

So your code had better to look like this :

```
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPushButton>

class UIBuilder {

    public:

        UIBuilder() : textEdit(new QTextEdit()), pushButton (new QPushButton())
        {
            // Do your stuff
            QObject::connect(textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)),
                             this, SLOT(enableSlot(const QString &)));
        }

        ~UIBuilder()
        {
            delete textEdit;
            delete pushButton;
        }

    protected:
        QLineEdit * textEdit;
        QPushButton * pushButton;

    public slots:

        void enableSlot(const QString &)
        {
            pushButton->setEnabled(true);
        }
};
```

**PS**: I guess you use a `QLineEdit` for the text.